# How do I account for spaces while reversing every word in a sentence?

Tags: c, char

Basically this program should take input from the user and reverse each word in the sentence. So if I ever "Hello World" is should print "olleH dlroW", but as of now it prints "dlroW olleH". So my program reverses the whole sentence and not just the specific words. Not really sure how to approach it. I gave it my best.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse(char *str, int start, int end)
{

    char temp;
    while (start < end)
    {
        if(isspace(str[start]))
        {
            printf("%s ", str);
            start++; 
        }
        else
        {
            temp = str[start];
            str[start] = str[end];
            str[end] = temp;
            start++;
            end--;
        }   
    }       
    return;
}

int main()
{
    char word[256];
    int i=0, bound;
    printf("Enter a string\n");
    fgets(word, 256, stdin);
    printf("%s", word);

    bound = strlen(word);
    reverse(word, i, bound-1);
    printf("%s\n", word);



}
```

Comment: @ETech: Neither the C programming language nor its standard libraries defines `vector`. If the question was about C++, that would be a reasonable approach.

Comment: Pardon for vector. Use char ** array instead.

Comment: Hint: rename `reverse` to `reverse_word` run through the sentence splitting at spaces; once you're done, reverse the accumulated result

Comment: First of all you should be looping `isspace` because there can many of them.  This way you will set a pointer at `first` char of a word (or end reversing at all if null char), now with another pointer starting at this found new `first` char of a word find it's `last` char and start reversing by swapping until pointers meet. Loop until end of string

Answer (score 3):

Track the point where you start and when you find a space - both integers. If you find a space get a substring from 'start'(first letter) to 'end'(space). Reverse the substring and put it back to original string and go on.

Answer (score 3):

fix like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse(char *str, int start, int end){
    char temp;
    while (start < end){
        temp = str[start];
        str[start++] = str[end];
        str[end--] = temp;
    }      
}

int main(void){
    char word[256];

    printf("Enter a string\n");
    fgets(word, 256, stdin);
    printf("%s", word);

    size_t pos = 0, start, end;
    do {
        start = (pos += strspn(word + pos, " \t"));
        end = start + strcspn(word + pos, " \t\n");
        reverse(word, start, end-1);
        pos = end;
    }while(start != end);

    printf("%s\n", word);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just change your reverse method to this. I hope this helps.

```
void reverse_word(char *word, int len){
    int i;
    int j = strcspn(word," ");
    int k = j;
    int check = k/2; // for keeping track of the middle char

    for (i = 0;  i< len ; ++i) {

        if(i == check) {
            j = strcspn((word+k)+1," ");  // get the next space if there is any
            i = k+1;
            j = j+k+1;
            k = j;
            check = i + ((j-i)/2);

        }

        --j;
        char c = word[i];
        word[i] = word[j];
        word[j] = c;
    }

}
```

results from test

> "Hello World working" reverse to --->>  olleH dlroW gnikrow