# Having trouble reversing parts of a string

Tags: c, string, reverse

This seemed like a simple idea when I decided to try it out, but know it's driving me nuts. 
I can reverse a whole string, but now I'm trying to reverse individual parts of a string. 
**Example:**

```
"pizza is amazing"  to "azzip si amazing"
```

Basically my program should reverse a string from **point a to b**, treating any words within it separately. My logic appears right (at least to me), but obviously something is wrong because my output is just the first word `"pizza"`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *reverse(char *a, int i, int j){    //reverse the words
    char temp;
    while(i<j){
        temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = temp;
        i++;
        j--;
    }
    return a;
}

char *words(char *a, int i, int j){    // identify if there are any words from a-b
    int count = i;
    while(i<j){
        if(a[i] == ' '){           // a space signifies the end of a word
            reverse(a , i-count, i);
                    count = 0;         //reset count for next word
            }
        i++;
        count++;
    }
    return a;
}

int main(){
    char a[50];
    char *a2;
    printf("Enter a string:\n);      //string input
    scanf("%s", a);

    int strlength = strlen(a) + 1;
    a2 = (char *)malloc(strlength*sizeof(char));
    strcpy( a2, a);

    printf("Reversed string:\n%s", words(a, 0, 4));  // create a-b range
    return 0;
}
```

I realize my problem is most likely within `words()`. I am out of ideas.

Comment: 1) Use `fgets(a, sizeof a, stdin)` or `scanf("%49[^\n]", a);` instead of  `scanf("%s", a);` Because `"%s"` of `scanf` can not contain space characters.

Comment: 2) `words(a, 0, 4)` : Why 4?. Are 0 and 4 word-based?

Comment: 3) [How do I account for spaces while reversing every word in a sentence?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42915023/971127)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY the range can be any number I just used a random number for now, but perhaps testing it out with  a number like 5 or 8 would be better.

Comment: So E.g case of `"pizza is amazing", 2, 12`, Is result `piazz si zamaing`?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY yes, I am only reversing from 2 to 12, if there are any words within that range, reverse each word seperatley. If a word starts or ends outside of the range, just reverse the parts within the range.

Comment: In such a case `if(a[i] == ' '){` is wrong. because In the following cases it does not include space. `"abcde fg hij", 0, 3`, `"abcde\n"`. Also  `reverse(a , i-count, i);` is incorrect as it inverts it, including the spaces found.

Comment: Please, accept my answer if it was satisfactory and helped you, else, tell me how can I help you more!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem 1:**

You should be more careful naming variables, understandable and meaningful names help the programmer and others reading your code. Keep in mind this is extremely important.

**Problem 2:**

When you pass the parameter `%s` to `scanf()`, it will read subsequent characters until a whitespace is found (whitespace characters are considered to be blank, newline and tab).

You can use `scanf("%[^\n]", a)` to read all characters until a newline is found.

For further reference on `scanf()`, take a look [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm).

**Problem 3:**

Take a look at the `words()` function, you're not storing a base index (from where to start reversing). The call to `reverse()` is telling it to reverse a single character (nothing changes).

You didn't specified if a whole word must be inside the range in order to be reversed or even if it is on the edge (ex: half in, half out). I'll assume the whole word must be inside the range, check out this modified version of the `words()` function:

```
char *words(char *str, int fromIndex, int toIndex){

    int i = fromIndex;
    int wordStartingIndex = fromIndex;

    /* 
    It is necessary to expand the final index by one in order
    get words bounded by the specified range. (ex: pizza (0, 4)).
    */

    toIndex += 1;

    /* Loop through the string. */

    while(i <= toIndex){

        if(str[i] == ' ' || str[i] == '\0' || str[i] == '\n'){

            reverse(str, wordStartingIndex, i-1);

            wordStartingIndex = (i + 1);

        }

        i++;

    }

    return str;
}
```

This should get you started. The function it is not perfect, you'll need to modify it in order to handle some special cases, such as the one I've mentioned.